# Antlr4 expressions are chaining

Tags: antlr4

from what i have read the way i defined my 'expression' this should provide me with the following:

This is my input:

```
xyz = a + b + c + d
```

This should be my output:

```
xyz = ( ( a + b ) + ( c + d) )
```

But instead i get:

```
xyz = ( a + (b + (c + d) ) )
```

I bet this has been solved before and i just wasnt able to find the solution.

```
statementList       : s=statement sl=statementList  #multipleStatementList
                    | s=statement                   #singleStatementList
                    ;

statement           : statementAssign
                    | statementIf
                    ;

statementAssign     : var=VAR ASSIGN expr=expression        #overwriteStatementAssign
                    | var=VAR PLUS ASSIGN expr=expression   #addStatementAssign
                    | var=VAR MINUS ASSIGN expr=expression  #subStatementAssign
                    ;


                    ;

expression          : BRACKET_OPEN expr=expression BRACKET_CLOSE                    #priorityExp
                    | left=expression operand=('*'|'/') right=expression            #mulDivExp
                    | left=expression operand=('+'|'-') right=expression            #addSubExp
                    | <assoc=right> left=expression POWER right=expression          #powExp
                    | variable=VAR                                                  #varExp
                    | number=NUMBER                                                 #numExp
                    ;



BRACKET_OPEN        : '(' ;
BRACKET_CLOSE       : ')' ;

ASTERISK            : '*' ;
SLASH               : '/' ;
PLUS                : '+' ;
MINUS               : '-' ;
POWER               : '^' ;
MODULO              : '%' ;


ASSIGN              : '=' ;

NUMBER              : [0-9]+ ;

VAR                 : [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]* ;

WS                  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the expression

```
 xyz = ( ( a + b ) + ( c + d) )
```

Then you'll need to control the binding of the `+` operator with parentheses just as you've done in your expected output.  Otherwise, with

```
 xyz = ( a + (b + (c + d) ) )
```

is the way the parser is going to parse it because  all the `+` operators have the same precedence, and the parser continues parsing until it reaches the end of the expression.

It recursively applies

```
left=expression operand=('+'|'-') right=expression
```

until the expression is completed.

and you get the grouping you got.  So use those parentheses, that's what they're for if you want to force the order of expression evaluation.  ;)

If you change your input to

xyz = a * b + c + d

you'll see what I mean about the precedence, because the multiplication rule appears before the addition rule -- and hence binds earlier -- which is a mathematical convention (lacking parentheses to group terms.)

You're doing it right and the parser is too.  Just group what you want if you want a specific binding order.

Comment: Oh, i guess i understood it wrong then.
Sadly, for my needs i want to have as few expressions as possible, because of the way i convert and export them lateron. And i dont want to have the user of my language deal with parentheses, but rather have my program optimize it for him. What would be the easiest way to archieve this?

Comment: @unobtanium An upvote and/or accept would motivate me further.  But just let the precedence of the operators handle the expressions, leave the parentheses as options for users who want to use them, but not necessary to do a + b + c.  I know what you mean about keeping it simple if you're making a domain-specific language.

Comment: Hm, i just checked, but it seems like it doesnt accually matter if i use parentheses or not (even with more variables and operations). The amount of expressions stays the same. Therefore, i will just leave it at that for right now.

Comment: @unobtanium Yes, as I said you're doing it right!  :)